# Four points that are pairwise equidistant from a third.

Tags: geometry

I need coordinates of four distinct points in the plane such that any two of them is equidistant from one of the remaining ones. If such a configuration exists, please give an instance of the the exact numerical value in the rectangular or the polar coordinates.

To be specific, if the points are $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, then
($AC=BC$ or $AD=BD$) and 
($AB=CB$ or $AD=CD$) and 
($AB=DB$ or $AC=DC$) and 
($BA=CA$ or $BD=CD$) and 
($BA=DA$ or $BC=DC$) and 
($CA=DA$ or $CB=DB$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this just be a parallelogram with angles of $60$ and $120$ degrees (two equilateral triangles of the same size that share a side)?

Consider the following plot:

$A = (0,0)$
$B = (-0.5,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$
$C = (0.5,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$
$D = (0,\sqrt{3})$

Each of $AB$, $AC$, $BD$, $CD$, and $BC$ are sides of equilateral triangles, and $AD$ bisects the shape and is equidistant from both $B$ and $C$.

Comment: I have not checked the coordinates, but the configuration is right. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are $6$ unordered pairs of two points, and four points;
for each pair there is a point equidistant from them.  Thus some point must correspond to at least two pairs.  Say that point is $A$.  The possible pairs that could be equidistant from it are $(B,C), (B,D), (C,D)$.  Any two of them have a point in common.  So $B,C,D$ must all be equidistant from $A$.  Now one of $C$ and $D$, let's say $C$, is equidistant from $A$ and $B$, so $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.  One of $B$ and $C$, let's say $B$, is equidistant from $A$ and $D$, and this will work if $ABD$ is an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Comment: I find that this answer clearly shows how the diagram is incrementally constructed and it can be improved if your diagram has labels $A, B, C, D$.

Comment: OK, added labels